# Handling expiration date of PASETO access token received from backend in React.js

Tags: reactjs, authentication, jwt, token, paseto

I'm working on a React.js project where the backend server is issuing PASETO (Platform-Agnostic Security Tokens) access tokens for authentication. I need to handle the expiration of these tokens on the client-side. The tokens contain an expiration date, and I would like to know how to extract and use this expiration date in my React.js application.

Could someone provide guidance or sample code on how to extract the expiration date from a PASETO access token and handle its expiration in a React.js application? Are there any libraries or best practices that can help with this task?

Thank you in advance for any help or suggestions!

I tried using various libraries like paseto, paseto.js, and jsonwebtoken to extract the expiration date from the PASETO access token in my React.js application. However, none of these libraries seemed to provide the desired functionality.

I expected these libraries to offer methods or functions that would allow me to easily decode the PASETO access token and retrieve the expiration date. However, despite following the documentation and examples provided by these libraries, I encountered issues such as incorrect or unexpected output, or even runtime errors.